# Getting A Player's Likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql, privacy

I have a Facebook iframe app and when the player logs into the app I wish to detect whether or not they have liked the community page attached to my app. I went about this by making the following FQL call:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id="<my_fan_page_id>"
```

I also read about a need for the [user_likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission that you can request from your users when they approve an app. I was concerned that I might need this permission in order to get the desired information but in my initial testing it appeared that I would not. Even though I had not requested that permission it appeared that I was pulling down the player's like information anyway.

Sadly a friend has an account, however, that will not provide this information to my app. Digging further, I experimented with the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and found that when I was logged in as him and tried an even more general request about his page likes the query still returned with an empty array. That query was:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me()
```

I'm assuming then that this means there is a privacy setting in the user account settings that allows a FB user to block providing this information by default, yes? If so, which setting is this in the user security settings and does that mean the only way to guarantee this information gets pulled down is by requesting the user_likes permission? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a special privacy setting, but yes, you need user_likes permission to query about the pages the user has liked.